# Docker compose - build order, database before the app

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using docker compose file to build a web app. In one image I have the webserver, php and other required extensions and packages. Docker file for the web app is inheriting public base image and extending it with custom commands. In another container I have mysql server. Now Im facing the issue where during initial build my app actually need live database connection but web container is always executed first and database one still not launched which of course leads to failure. I tried to add depends_on but as I see this only affects start order, not the build one.

I heard for rocker and other extensions solving the issue but is there any way to do this natively ? As far as I could research I see that there is no viable option which doesn't make sense as people request it a lot.

Comment: A better way to do this is not make them dependent on each other. The web app should have a good fallback for the web app until the database is up and running. It could check ever xxxms to figure out if it's ready yet. I didn't put this as an answer since it is a different question than you asked.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it is option for you but you could build your custom script.

Let's say that you would have two docker-compose files.

- One for building your mysql database
- The second one for your webapps

First you could lunch mysql database docker-compose file with two mysql images

- One will lunch your database
- The second one will launch a script until the mysql db is ready.

After both containers will finish starting you can start launching docker-compose with your webapps and you will be **ensured that database is up and running**.

This approach needs some custom script to process but can be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is one way to go. For my use case maybe it is better to go with command option in yml file and write a custom bash script which will actually take care for everything. I have not tried but my guess is that docker compose will consider depends_on option and this will work out.

Answer (score 2):

Following docker document, depends_on will not wait for db to be “ready” before starting web. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, follow the doc here 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: Exactly. I use https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it for exactly that purpose - waiting for the database to be available before I start the other applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I mentioned bellow I may give a try the command option along with depends_on A custom bash script may get the things done in the right way.